# How to create indexes automatically in embedded neo4j?

Tags: java, indexing, neo4j

I want to auto index on a property of Particular node.
According to this documentation, we have to provide property name and that will get indexed.
http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/auto-indexing.html

I have two nodes **node1** and **node2** and both have same property as **name**. I want to index only on property **name** on node **node1** not on **node2**. How do I do this at runtime and not using CYPHER ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Autoindexes (as the name implies) do automatically index a given property name.

If you want to explicitly index `name` only for specific nodes it makes sense to use schema indexes. This requires that `node1` and `node2` carry different labels.

If that is not an option, you can go with manual indexes and decide on a per node what should go to the index. Writing to a manual index is not possible in Cypher, you need to use either Java API or the respective [REST Call](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-indexes.html#rest-api-add-node-to-index) instead.

I've summed up the different kind of indexes in Neo4j in a [blog post](http://blog.armbruster-it.de/2013/12/indexing-in-neo4j-an-overview/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer Stefan. I wanted to achieve schema indexing using Java API not Cypher as mentioned in the question. I found the neo4j documentation for the same.

Comment: Your question did not mention you're using labels. Without them, you cannot use schema indexes. Also your question did not mention you're looking for a java API solution - so I assumed it's platform independent - sorry for misunderstanding.

Answer (score 4):

I found the neo4j documentation for creating schema indexes on property of Particular node using java code

Adding code here. This might help someone like me :)

```
IndexDefinition indexDefinition;
try ( Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx() ){
Schema schema = graphDb.schema();
indexDefinition = schema.indexFor( DynamicLabel.label( "node1" ) )
        .on( "name" )
        .create();
tx.success();
}
```

http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/tutorials-java-embedded-new-index.html